# I am looking to use a Deutsch DTP series connector. It appears they only come in 2 cavity and 4 cavity layouts, how do I seal it with only 3 wires?

Tags: connector

DTP connectors are known to be waterproof. If I am only using 3 of the 4 cavities there will be an open hole for the fourth cavity which will make it not waterproof. How do I go about using this connector with only 3 wires?

Comment: A photo and datasheet link would be useful for anyone trying to understand your question or for a future reader with the same problem. There's an [Edit] link below your question and a link icon on the editor toolbar. Welcome to EE.SE.

Answer (score 0):

No need for a plug: if there's no wire, the gasket closes fully.